# Why isn't Wordpress loading my CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a site for a client and for some reason Wordpress has stopped loading my extra css files located in side a folder called css which is inside the theme folder.

The code I've used is below

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/ MY CSS FILES " rel="stylesheet" />
```

The rendered HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> My blog</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts from Google -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,400italic,700italic|Lora:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Homepage Slider -->
    <script src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        captions: true
    });
    });
    </script>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


        <link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch">
        <link href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/img/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
        <link href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/img/icons/touch.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed">

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Just another WordPress site">

                <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"http:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/72x72\/","ext":".png","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/www.samuraisound.co.uk\/dev\/alexiafrangakis\/php\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.2"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var c=b.createElement("canvas"),d=c.getContext&&c.getContext("2d");return d&&d.fillText?(d.textBaseline="top",d.font="600 32px Arial","flag"===a?(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55356,56812,55356,56807),0,0),c.toDataURL().length>3e3):(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55357,56835),0,0),0!==d.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0])):!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g;c.supports={simple:d("simple"),flag:d("flag")},c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.simple&&c.supports.flag||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='aps-animate-css-css'  href='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/plugins/accesspress-social-icons/css/animate.css?ver=1.3.1' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='aps-frontend-css-css'  href='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/plugins/accesspress-social-icons/css/frontend.css?ver=1.3.1' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='normalize-css'  href='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/normalize.css?ver=1.0' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='html5blank-css'  href='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/style.css?ver=1.0' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/js/lib/conditionizr-4.3.0.min.js?ver=4.3.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/js/lib/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js?ver=2.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/js/scripts.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/plugins/accesspress-social-icons/js/frontend.js?ver=1.3.1'></script>
        <script>
        // conditionizr.com
        // configure environment tests
        conditionizr.config({
            assets: 'http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine',
            tests: {}
        });
        </script>


    </head>
    <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top" class="home logged-in">

         <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php">I Am Press</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
     </nav>




<!-- Intro Section -->
    <section id="intro" class="intro-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bx-wrapper">
                                <ul class="bxslider">
                    <li><div class="blog-featured">
                        <img src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/IMG_5939-750x510.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="IMG_5939.PNG" />                            <div class="featured-square">
                                <div class="featured-title" rel="bookmark" ><a class="featured-title-class" href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/travel/city-guide-istanbul/">City Guide: Istanbul</a></div>
                                    <div class="featured-excerpt">
                                               Over the May bank holiday I took a quick trip to Istanbul. This beautiful city is soaked in history and culture. With only three days to spend there I didn&#8217;t have much time to explore the city, therefore I have picked my favourite parts from my trip. What I did When it comes to being&#8230; <a class="view-article" href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/travel/city-guide-istanbul/">View Article</a>                         </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                                                            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <main role="main">
        <!-- section -->
        <section>
            <!-- Latest Section -->
    <section id="about" class="latest-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Latest Stories</h1>
                </div>
            </div>            
                        <div class="sec-one-wrapper">
                <div class="sec-one-image">
                                         <img src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_7951-825x510.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="IMG_7951" />                </div>
                <div class="sec-one-time">
                    <div class="latest-category">
                    <div class="featured-cat" style="color:#ede625;">Fashion</div>                    </div> 
                    <div class="the-time">June 21, 2015</div>
                </div>                               
                <div class="sec-one-title">
                    <a class="sec-one-title-link" href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/fashion/brown/">Brown and out</a>
                </div>           
            </div>

                        <div class="sec-one-wrapper">
                <div class="sec-one-image">
                                         <img src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/DSC_0712-825x510.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="DSC_0712" />                </div>
                <div class="sec-one-time">
                    <div class="latest-category">
                    <div class="featured-cat" style="color:#ede625;">Fashion</div>                    </div> 
                    <div class="the-time">June 18, 2015</div>
                </div>                               
                <div class="sec-one-title">
                    <a class="sec-one-title-link" href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/fashion/boom-boom/">Boom Boom</a>
                </div>           
            </div>

                        <div class="sec-one-wrapper">
                <div class="sec-one-image">
                                         <img src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_6153-825x510.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="IMG_6153.JPG" />                </div>
                <div class="sec-one-time">
                    <div class="latest-category">
                    <div class="featured-cat" style="color:#ede625;">Fashion</div>                    </div> 
                    <div class="the-time">June 11, 2015</div>
                </div>                               
                <div class="sec-one-title">
                    <a class="sec-one-title-link" href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/fashion/camouflage/">Camouflage</a>
                </div>           
            </div>
                                             </div>
    </section>



            <!-- Editors Favorites Section -->
    <section id="services" class="editors-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="left-side">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Editors Favorites</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>


            <div class="sec-two-wrapper">
                <div class="sec-two-media">
                    <div class="sec-two-image">
                         <img src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_7951-150x150.jpg" class="sec-two-img wp-post-image" alt="IMG_7951" />                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sec-two-text">
                    <div class="sec-two-time">
                        <a class="cat"><ul class="post-categories">
    <li><a href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/category/fashion/" rel="tag">Fashion</a></li></ul></a> June 21, 2015                    </div>                               
                    <div class="sec-two-title">
                        <a href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/fashion/brown/" title="Brown and out">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="sec-two-excerpt">
                        A simple neutral outfit can never go wrong. At the moment I am loving brown. I used to always wear shirts so I thought I&#8217;d throw on one of my old favourites. Unfortunately it is very big for me nowadays but I just can&#8217;t bring myself to get rid of it. The back of the&#8230; <a class="view-article" href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/fashion/brown/">View Article</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="sec-two-wrapper">
                <div class="sec-two-media">
                    <div class="sec-two-image">
                         <img src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/DSC_0712-150x150.jpg" class="sec-two-img wp-post-image" alt="DSC_0712" />                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sec-two-text">
                    <div class="sec-two-time">
                        <a class="cat"><ul class="post-categories">
    <li><a href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/category/fashion/" rel="tag">Fashion</a></li></ul></a> June 18, 2015                    </div>                               
                    <div class="sec-two-title">
                        <a href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/fashion/boom-boom/" title="Boom Boom">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="sec-two-excerpt">
                        I am absolutely obsessed with my new Boom Boom The Label dress. From the fabric to the fit it is perfect. This particular dress is called the Tamera slit back dress. It also comes without the slit at the back, however for ease of movement as it is a bodycon dress I chose to buy the&#8230; <a class="view-article" href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/fashion/boom-boom/">View Article</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="sec-two-wrapper">
                <div class="sec-two-media">
                    <div class="sec-two-image">
                         <img src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_6153-150x150.jpg" class="sec-two-img wp-post-image" alt="IMG_6153.JPG" />                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sec-two-text">
                    <div class="sec-two-time">
                        <a class="cat"><ul class="post-categories">
    <li><a href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/category/fashion/" rel="tag">Fashion</a></li></ul></a> June 11, 2015                    </div>                               
                    <div class="sec-two-title">
                        <a href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/fashion/camouflage/" title="Camouflage">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="sec-two-excerpt">
                                   &nbsp; Summer is almost here! Finally, I got to wear my new Enza Costa dress. It&#8217;s a really simple ribbed jersey grey dress with a curved hem that accentuates curves. I teamed it with my favourite Adidas sliders and a camouflage jacket; after all camouflage is the new black! Jacket &#8211; Coming soon Dress Sliders &lt;a href=&#8221;http://www.bloglovin.com/blog/13656875/?claim=2n8pkw6dgnk&#8221;&gt;Follow&#8230; <a class="view-article" href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/fashion/camouflage/">View Article</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
        <!-- /section -->
    </main>
<!-- pagination -->
<div class="pagination">
    <span class='page-numbers current'>1</span>
<a class='page-numbers' href='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/page/2/'>2</a>
<a class='page-numbers' href='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/page/3/'>3</a>
<span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>
<a class='page-numbers' href='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/page/20/'>20</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/page/2/">Next &raquo;</a></div>
<!-- /pagination -->
<!-- sidebar -->
<aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">

    <!-- search -->
<form class="search" method="get" action="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php" role="search">
    <input class="search-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="To search, type and hit enter.">
    <button class="search-submit" type="submit" role="button">Search</button>
</form>
<!-- /search -->

    <div class="sidebar-widget">
            </div>

    <div class="sidebar-widget">
            </div>

</aside>
<!-- /sidebar -->


        <script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var countVars = {"disqusShortname":"alexiafrangakis"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/plugins/disqus-comment-system/media/js/count.js?ver=4.2.2'></script>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <section id="footer" class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-widgets">
                <div id="footer-widget-one">
                </div>
                <div id="footer-widget-two">
                </div>
                <div id="footer-widget-three">
                </div>
                <div id="footer-widget-four">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <div id="footer-credits">
                <div class="credits-left">&copy; I Am Press 2015 </div>
                <div class="credits-right">Beautifully hand-coded by <a href="#">Darius Carter</a></div> 
            </div>
        </div>


    </section>



    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.samuraisound.co.uk/dev/alexiafrangakis/php/wp-content/themes/I%20Am%20Press%20Magazine/js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>

</body>

</html>

<!-- Dynamic page generated in 0.350 seconds. -->
<!-- Cached page generated by WP-Super-Cache on 2015-07-09 20:32:03 -->
```

Comment: When you say "has stopped loading", was it working before? Did you change anything?

Comment: It was working fine. I don't think I changed anything at all ( apart from uploading an updated css file to that same folder, but I've replaced it with the original file and still no luck ).

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console, e.g. 404 / not found?

Comment: It's completely error free

Comment: Please post the **rendered** HTML. You're probably using relative paths.

Comment: @Dai I've edited the question with the rendered HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows 
`href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/css/ MY CSS FILES' ?> "`

Comment: I don't see how this is going to result in different output.

Comment: Without php code (like /css/ MY CSS FILES) , Breaking url in two parts. First part is working as url and second part  is working as just display text.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use wp_enqueue_scripts function for adding custom css/js files because it loads file before custom files added in header/footer.

```
function add_theme_css() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'cssfile', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/file.css');


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_css' );
```